# Matrix notation

Tags: matrices

I was making matrix exercises when I ran into the matrix notation $X^{-2}$

Where $X$ is a $n \times n$ matrix. What is a matrix to the power $-2$?

Please provide me an answer because I couldn't find it anywhere else on the web.

Comment: Could it be a typo?

Comment: No I already found it the answer. Thanks. It's the product of two inverser so X^(-1)X(-1)

Answer (score 3):

In general for an $nxn$ matrix $A$, $A^k = A*A *...*A$ with the right hand side being multiplied $k$ times (which is well defined because of the associativity of matrixes).

In your case $A^{-2} = {(A^{-1})}^2 = A^{-1}*A^{-1}$, of course provided $A^{-1}$ exists.